# Unity ScrollRect scrolls the text field, but not text

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling to create a simple scrollable text box in Unity. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWOvwegLDl0) and others, but instead of the text scrolling like it should, it moves the **entire text object** up and down.

In the hierarchy, it is simply a panel with a text child.

[image]

Here's what the Panel looks like

[image]

And here's the textlog

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: You say "_it moves the entire text object_" instead of "_the text scrolling_" but that's exactly what a `ScrollRect` does; you provide it a `RectTransform` as its "content" and then it scrolls that object. Nothing is behaving incorrectly.

Comment: @Foggzie But in tutorials I've seen that's how they scroll the text. Even in that video you can see them do the same exact thing and yet the text scrolls without moving the transform. If ScrollRect isn't the answer, then what is?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. I didn't realize they were using a UI mask to achieve the effect.